# Получение исходников страницы при помощи Awesomium

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

Всем снова здравствуйте, я уже задавал вопрос по Awesomium, но мне так никто не ответил, но на просторах интернета я нашёл такую строку:

```
 string mysite = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString();
```

Которая не работает, вылетает исключение "The WebCore is not initialized.".
Объясните пожалуйста, что не так и где моя ошибка, никаких свойств типам WebCore, я не нашёл.
Так же нашёл пример на официальном сайте но скопировав его у меня снова ничего не получилось.

Вот полный код

```
    public Form1()
    {
        if (!WebCore.IsInitialized)
            WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig()
            {
                HomeURL = new Uri("http://www.awesomium.com"),
                RemoteDebuggingPort = 2229,
                LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose
            });
        InitializeComponent();
        string mysite = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString();

    }
```

Comment: А почему бы не просто загрузить документ через `new WebClient().DownloadString(uri)`?

Comment: Вообщем я получаю вот такую ересь "<title>Р›СЋРґРё, РєРѕС‚РѕСЂС‹Рј СЌС‚Рѕ РїРѕРЅСЂР°РІРёР»РѕСЃСЊ</title>"

Comment: Почему ересь? Вы просто что-то напутали с кодировкой. Это юникодная строка «Люди, которым это понравилось», байты которой интерпретированы как CP1251.

Comment: Спасибо вам, что всё показали и рассказали=)

Answer (score 1):

У него есть событие OnDocumentLoaded или похожее на это. Выполните это:

```
string mysite = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString();
```

в нём.

Но согласен с коментарием, проще сделать new WebClient().DownloadString(uri) возможно совметсно с [WebClient.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx)